# No asigna valor a un puntero del tipo float

Tags: c

Tengo una funcion que recibe 3 punteros del tipo float, dentro de la funcion lo que hago es crear un puntero que apunte hacia el valor recibido por parametros, e intento agregar un valor en la posicion de memoria, pero al imprimirlo me tira que es 0(Que es con lo que la inicialice)

```
int main(){
    float lodgingCost = 0;
    float foodCost = 0;
    float transportCost = 0;
    menuMantenimient(&lodgingCost, &foodCost, &transportCost);
}

int menuMantenimient(float lodgingCost, float foodCost, float transportCost) {
    float *buffLodging = &lodgingCost; //Asigno la direccion de memoria ;
    float *buffFood = &foodCost;//Asigno la direccion de memoria ;
    float *buffTransport = &transportCost;//Asigno la direccion de memoria ;
    buffLodging = 100,0;//Agrego un valor a la posicion de memoria
    buffFood =  1000,0;//Agrego un valor a la posicion de memoria
    buffTransport = 10000,0;//Agrego un valor a la posicion de memoria
    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f",buffLodging ,buffFood,buffLodging); // Imprime 0 en las 3
}
```

Comment: No estás indicando en el método que estás pasando un apuntador a float. Tu método declara que va a recibir variables del tipo float.

Comment: Los punteros tienes que usarlos en los parametros, no dentro de la funcion. Y si usas la variable solo asi, no estas accediendo el valor, sino a la direccion de memoria. Tienes que *desreferenciar* los punteros. Tiene que ser `*buffLodging = 100.0`, y `printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", *buffLodging, *buffFood, *buffLodging);`.

Comment: Notese que los decimales tienen que ser con un punto. De la forma en la que lo estas haciendo estas utilizando el [operador coma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do). En lugar de asignarle 100 a la variable, le estas asignando 0.

Comment: @Jacobo como deberia indicarle a la funcion?, te referis al prototipo?

Comment: `int menuMantenimient(float *lodgingCost, float *foodCost, float *transportCost)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código no debería compilar por varias razones.

Los literales de float dividen su parte decimal con un punto y terminan en `f`.

```
float a = 1.23f;
float b = 1.0f;
float c = 0.01f;
```

Sin la `f` son literales de tipo `double`.

---

Los parámetros no tienen las mismas direcciones de memoria que tus variables de la función `main`. Si la idea es que modifique las variables de`main` o cualquier otra función, verías que no se efectúa ningún cambio sobre ellas. Me refiero a esta parte del código:

```
int menuMantenimient(float lodgingCost, float foodCost, float transportCost) {
    float *buffLodging = &lodgingCost; //Asigno la direccion de memoria ;
    float *buffFood = &foodCost;//Asigno la direccion de memoria ;
    float *buffTransport = &transportCost;
    ...
}
```

---

Estás pasando una serie de punteros a la función:

```
//              (float*)       (float*)   (float*)
menuMantenimient(&lodgingCost, &foodCost, &transportCost);
```

Pero la función recibe valores de tipo float:

```
int menuMantenimient(float lodgingCost, float foodCost, float transportCost){
    ...
}
```

---

Para acceder al valor al que apunta un puntero (desreferenciarlo) debes usar el operador `*`:

```
*buffLodging = 100.0;
*buffFood =  1000.0;
*buffLodging= 10000.0;

// Con printf también tienes que hacer esto o estarías haciendo
// que interprete una dirección de memoria como un valor de tipo float
printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", *buffLodging , *buffFood , *buffLodging);
```

---

Finalmente el código te quedaría así:

```
int main(){
    float lodgingCost = 0;
    float foodCost = 0;
    float transportCost = 0;
    menuMantenimient(&lodgingCost, &foodCost, &transportCost);
}

int menuMantenimient(float* lodgingCost, float* foodCost, float* transportCost) {
    *lodgingCost = 100.0f; //Agrego un valor a la posicion de memoria
    *foodCost =  1000.0f; //Agrego un valor a la posicion de memoria
    *transportCost = 10000.0f; //Agrego un valor a la posicion de memoria
    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", *lodgingCost, *foodCost, *transportCost);
}
```